# How to find all matched elements from array of objects in mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Schema:

```
new Schema({
    productId: String,
    types: [{
        productType: String,
        lastModified: Date
    }]
});
```

Query:

```
{
  productId: "1",
  email: "test@test.com",
  productType: "test",
}
```

I tried this but its returning only first matched element:

```
const productType = 'test';
const result = await this.model(email)
.find(
    { productId, 'types.productType': productType },
    { 'types.$': productType }
).lean();
```

with aggregate, it return empty array result:

```
const result = await this.model(email).aggregate([
    { $match: { productId, 'types.productType': 'productType' } },
    {
        $project: {
            types: {
                $filter: {
                    input: '$types',
                    as: 'r',
                    cond: { $eq: ['$$r.productType', productType] }
                }
            },
            _id: 0
        }
    }
]);
```

I need to find all matching elements where projection `$` returns the first matched

Comment: Please share your document structure

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Retrieve only the queried element in an object array in MongoDB collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3985214/retrieve-only-the-queried-element-in-an-object-array-in-mongodb-collection)

Comment: @RajdeepDebnath Added schema

Comment: Ok, you do not need projection. `this.model(email)
.find(
    { productId, 'types.productType': productType },).lean()` will return all matching elements

Comment: @RajdeepDebnath If I don't use projection then its returning only `{ productType: 'test'}` instead of all properties in object

Comment: Well, it should return everything if you don't use projection. Can you share some data, then I can test your query?

Comment: `{`
  `productID: "1",`
 `email: "test@test.com",`
  `productType: "test"`
`}`

Comment: @RajdeepDebnath its okay I figured it out. Thanks